# JQuery adding li element causes misalignment

Tags: jquery

This is driving me nuts, jquery adding a simple li element to a ul, causes the jquery added li elements to be out of alignment with the elements that were there as part of original DOM.

Run the JS Fiddle and click on "Add New".
The li child elements from the original DOM versus the jquery added ones, are virtually the same, and i cannot see any padding differences in the chrome inspector.

See image of alignment issue of the 2 jquery added li elements at the top.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/advocate/hg8z0kvm/

```js
(function() {

  $('#addnew').click(function() {

    htmlCode = "<li>" +
      "<input type=\"checkbox\">" +
      "<input type=\"text\" name=\"desc\" placeholder=\"Description...\">" +

      "</li>";
    $("#thelist").prepend(htmlCode);


  });

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <ul id="thelist">
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <input type="text" name="desc" placeholder="Enter Desc...">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <input type="text" name="desc" placeholder="Enter Desc...">
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
<input type="submit" id="addnew" value="AddNew">
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the spaces on the HTML code. You can remove them from the html between the tags and there's no difference anymore:

```js
(function() {

  $('#addnew').click(function() {

    htmlCode = "<li>" +
      "<input type=\"checkbox\">" +
      "<input type=\"text\" name=\"desc\" placeholder=\"Description...\">" +
      "<input type=\"url\" name=\"url\" placeholder=\"URL...\">" +
      "</li>";
    $("#thelist").prepend(htmlCode);

  });

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <ul id="thelist">

    <li>
      <input type="checkbox"><input type="text" name="desc" placeholder="Enter Desc..."><input type="url" name="url" placeholder="URL">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox"><input type="text" name="desc" placeholder="Enter Desc..."><input type="url" name="url" placeholder="URL">
    </li>

  </ul>
</form>

<input type="submit" id="addnew" value="AddNew">
```

Comment: Alternatively you could add them to the JavaScript code.

Comment: There's also a css rule you can use.